# How can I create a normal integer distribution in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

The normal distribution:
    `std::normal_distribution<T>`
only accepts a real-valued type such as `float` or `double`, why doesn't it accept an integer type?

How can I create a normal integer distribution?

Comment: Counter-question: Why would anyone need a discrete distribution if you can easily convert `double` and `float` values to `int`?

Comment: The normal distribution is by definition continuous. There are discrete distributions that approximate the normal distribution.

Comment: I guess they don't! :)

Comment: @JosephMansfield, yeah, it's called a binomial distribution.

Comment: Why this question was put on hold makes no sense to me.  If you want an opinion based question see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc.  That question (and especially the answer) is equivalent to (should I use VI instead of Emacs) and yet the question and answer have about 500 votes.

Comment: That question was asked 5 years ago. The rules were different back then. We have become more strict over time as we've discovered how the opinion-based questions cause serious detrimental effects on the quality of questions over time.

Comment: That said - you are now asking a specific question... so I'll nominate this question for re-opening.

Comment: @Moberg funny enough that Stroustrup gives an example with `normal_distribution<int>` at http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-random

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know next to nothing about C++11 but I know a little math (or I did at one point) and a discrete normal distribution is called a [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). In fact a normal distribution is the binomial distribution when you let `n` go to infinity.

So assuming C++11 has a binomial distribution then you have a discrete normal distribution.
Why don't you try `std::binomial_distribution`?

You might also want to read up on the [de Moivre–Laplace theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

[image]

Comment: And you are totally right: there is a class named [`std::binomial_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/binomial_distribution) in the standard library.

Comment: It's only symmetric for p = 1/2, although you can get away with other p-values when you have sufficiently large n.

Comment: @pjs, yes, that's why de Moivre–Laplace theorem is a special case of the central limit theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the generated random value to an integer.

```
std::normal_distribution<float> noise(0, 2.f);
randomValue = (int) round(noise(engine));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need to round to preserve the distribution.

Comment: Yes otherwise the expected value would be shifted.