# Bug in std::random when generating normal_distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, normal-distribution

Here is my code. It suppose to generate `normal_distribution`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    // Initialize seed .
    std::mt19937 gena;
    boost::random::mt19937 genb;
    gena.seed( 10 );
    genb.seed( 10 );

    std::normal_distribution<> norma;
    boost::random::normal_distribution<> normb;

    std::cout << "STD BOOST" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
        std::cout << norma(gena) << ' ' << normb(genb) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with `gcc-8.1` on arch-linux, and I get the following:

`STD BOOST
-0.0512656 1.16196
-1.90693 -0.742973
1.23919 -1.10165
-0.212754 1.03149
-0.376303 0.597194
0.0660327 -0.12573
-1.01706 1.10728
0.907624 -0.370934
-0.682124 -0.404068
-0.461218 -0.46376
0.965666 -0.607265
0.560664 -1.44186
0.749932 0.449968
-0.31456 -0.268649
0.366249 0.986499
0.608089 -0.500526
-1.08684 -0.0215645
0.120559 -0.805144
1.40203 0.390409
-0.434259 0.0991071`

I use the same code on a Mac machine `(Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`); and I get the following:

`STD BOOST
-1.90693 1.16196
-0.0512656 -0.742973
-0.212754 -1.10165
1.23919 1.03149
0.0660327 0.597194
-0.376303 -0.12573
0.907624 1.10728
-1.01706 -0.370934
-0.461218 -0.404068
-0.682124 -0.46376
0.560664 -0.607265
0.965666 -1.44186
-0.31456 0.449968
0.749932 -0.268649
0.608089 0.986499
0.366249 -0.500526
0.120559 -0.0215645
-1.08684 -0.805144
-0.434259 0.390409
1.40203 0.0991071`

Note the first column which uses `std::random` is different; but if you look closely, first column have many elements common but seem to be shuffled.

I am worried after one test broke on Travis (that means, Ububtu-14.04 and xcode-9.2 will show the same results) after we replaced our old normal distribution generator in favor of `std::random`.

Is it a bug? Or I am doing something wrong?  BOOST is doing OK.

Comment: IIRC, `std::*_distribution` are implementation-dependent, but random engines themselves should produce the same result.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed. rng's are producing same sequence. In fact, `uniform_distribution` is also producing same sequence.

Comment: It's a duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903356/c11-random-number-distributions-are-not-consistent-across-platforms-what-al

Comment: When doing tests, you should stub in an RNG that you know will produce the same results every time. Otherwise, you will get test failures.

Answer (score 3):

When you use different compilers (or even versions of compilers) the pseudo random numbers in the normal distribution aren't obliged to be the same just because you've used the same seed.  I wouldn't *rely* on the sequence being the same unless I was using the same compiler, compiler version and possibly optimisation settings - check the compiler implementation documentation if you've reason to care.

It's unsurprising that boost is more consistent because you're presumably using the same implementation despite the compiler difference.

Comment: The sequences produced by **generators** with the same seed are required to be the same on all implementations. The sequences produced by feeding the output from a generator to a **distribution** are not required to be the same even if the generators produce the same output sequence.

Comment: @PeteBecker: quite so - perhaps my typo "in the distribute" rather than "distribution" makes it less clear that's what I'm saying (now fixed).  I also provided the link to the duplicate Q where answers emphasise that distinction (though someone deleted my comment about the duplicate when  πάντα ῥεῖ closed this as a duplicate).

Comment: The wording is very confusing. "pseudo random numbers in the distribution"... I took that to mean the compiler distribution. It sounds like the random number generators are allowed to give different sequences for different seeds.

Comment: @Galik: Oh :-/.  I'll qualify distribution with "normal" then.  Cheers